# Determine the holomorph of $\Bbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, holomorph

Let $G= \Bbb{Z}_3$ then determine the holomorph of $G$ which is

$$\Bbb{Z}_3 \rtimes_\phi \text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_3)$$

where $\phi :{\rm Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_3) \rightarrow {\rm Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_3$) is the identity.

My gut intuition tells me this is either $\Bbb{Z}_6$ or $S_3$ as the order is $3$ times $\phi(3)=2$ which is 6. How do I show what the holomorph is of this given group?

I know the binary operation is defined via

$$(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2)=(h_1 \phi(k_1)(h_2),k_1k_2)$$

where $h_i \in \Bbb{Z}_3$ and $k_i \in{\rm Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_3)$. So is it enough to determine whether or not the semi direct product is abelian or not? If so how do you show commutativity of the semi direct product?

Comment: It is not the direct product of $C_3$ with $C_2$ since $\phi$ is not trivial. So we obtain $D_3$, which is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: so since its not the direct product, its non abelian? @DietrichBurde

Comment: Yes, it is then nonabelian.